# Remotely manage Gatekeeper

Tags: macos, mobile-device-management, gatekeeper

I've been searching high and low for some service that will do this. Looking for something that can be installed on multiple machines, that has a nice dashboard that can tell me at the very least whether gatekeeper is enabled on each of the machines. Bonus to be able to manage it remotely.

The only service I've come across that does this is [Casper](http://www.jamfsoftware.com/products/casper-suite/), but they are super expensive. Has anybody come across another solution?

Comment: How many machines are you administering? You may have better luck on ServerFault if it's a large number or an enterprise setting. In any case, [puppet](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppet_%28software%29) is extremely powerful, it may be more than you need, though.

Comment: right now looking at somewhere in the region of 25 machines. Will look into Puppet, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much any MDM can enable / monitor gatekeeper status.

If you want inexpensive, you can use Server.app for $20 and go up from there. Apple Remote Desktop also lets you automate things. Heck, you could set up ssh keys and use that to run `spctl` by script.

```
spctl --status
```

The manual page shows you how to enable and disable gatekeeper with `spctl` as well as white list certain apps if you want that level of fine grained control.